# Using an enum to set a property during initialization in swift

Tags: swift, enums

I'd like to learn how to set a unique gifted dance property during initialization using a breakdances enum that uses strings.  I figured it would work but when I tried different variations of setting the property in init, I would get compile errors such as "assigning a property to itself" and many others.  I've run out of ideas but I know its possible because some Cocoa classes do this during initialization such as UITableView when selecting preferred style.

```
import Foundation


enum Breakdances: String {
    case HoppityHop = "Hop Hop Hop and two step is what I do usually"
    case Greyjoy = "I made up this dance, pretty cool huh?"
    case ButtSwirl = "Let's do the butt swril"
    case PsychMovementWithHands = "Psych, Psych, Psych! Psych"
    case TheDab = "Dabbbbb!"
    case TheBump = "I'm doing the rump bump dance"
}




class Monkeys: Animals, canPlayAroundProtocol, randomJungleActivity {
    static var monkeysPopulation: Int = 0

    var uniqueGiftedDance: Breakdances

    override init(name:String){
        super.init(name: name)
        self.uniqueGiftedDance = uniqueGiftedDance
        Monkeys.monkeysPopulation += 1

    }

    override func makeSound() -> String {
        energyLevel -= 4

        return "Ah ah ah"
    }

    override func eatFood(){
        energyLevel += 2

    }

    override func sleep(){


    }

    func play(){

        let reducedEnergy = energyLevel - 8
        if reducedEnergy < 0 {
            print("\(name) is too tired, I don't have enough energy")
        }else {
        print("Oooo Oooo Oooo")
        print("\(name)'s energy level is now \(reducedEnergy)")
        }

    }

    func startUniqueJungleAct(){

        print(uniqueGiftedDance)

        print("Swinging from a tree and throwing banannas")
    }

    deinit {
        Monkeys.monkeysPopulation -= 1

    }

}
```

Here is my parent class:

```
import Foundation

protocol canPlayAroundProtocol {
    func play()
}

protocol randomJungleActivity {
    func startUniqueJungleAct()
}

class Animals {
    static var animalPopulation: Int = 0

    var name: String!

    var energyLevel: Int = 100


    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name

        Animals.animalPopulation += 1

        print("Another animal has given birth, animal population is now \(Animals.animalPopulation)")
    }

    func makeSound() -> String{
        energyLevel -= 3
        return "null"
    }

    func eatFood() {
        energyLevel += 5

    }

    func sleep(){
        energyLevel += 10

    }

    static func junglePerformSoundOff(){


    }

    func bathroomSound(){


    }

    deinit {
        Animals.animalPopulation -= 1
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you want `uniqueGiftedDance` to come from?

Comment: Your posted code has a lot of irrelevant material. People don't want to wade through all of that to get to the point. Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Alexander thanks and I'd like to set it when creating new instances of Monkey.  So each monkey have have their own uniqueGiftedDance.  I hope I answered your question.

Comment: So you'll want to give it as a parameter during initialization, correct?

Comment: @Alexander correct

Comment: So then... add it as a parameter to the initializer

Comment: @Alexander I agree and thought this would work but Xcode shows the error "Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a new parameter to your initializer.

```
init(name: String, uniqueGiftedDance: Breakdances) {
    super.init(name: name)
    self.uniqueGiftedDance = uniqueGiftedDance
    Monkeys.monkeysPopulation += 1

}
```

Comment: I tried this as well but get the error "Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass".

Comment: So you'll have to get rid of the `override` keyword, to indicate that you no longer intend for this to be an `override` of an existing initializer form the superclass. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Removing override and adding "self.uniqueGiftedDance = uniqueGiftedDance" above super.init DID ITTT!!!  Much much much obliged @Alexander !

Comment: @user6510422 Do you understand the point of the `override` keyword?

Comment: I think so and I'd like to say that by keeping override there and then calling super.init inside the function is contradicting isn't it?  I think I didn't want to get ride of the super.init function completely but wanted to be able to add onto it.  I probably should have used an extension huh?  I don't want to overcomplicate things based on what I read but need to practice more.  Is this what you would have said?

Comment: Nope, it's not like that at all. Suppose you have an application that uses some framework with a class called `Window`. `Window` has a `draw()` method. Suppose you make a subclass, `MyWindow`, which overrides `draw()` so that it draws in the way you want. The framework calls `draw()` for you, such as the override in `MyWindow`, or the original one in `Window`. Now suppose the framework vendor, for whatever reason, decides to change the name of `draw()` to `drawWindow()`. Now your `draw()` method is no longer an override, it's just its own new method. *continued in chat...*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132448/discussion-between-alexander-and-user6510422).